# What exactly is the relation between Hadoop and SQL in a nutshell? Will Hadoop render SQL obsolete? Please suggest

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, hadoop

I was all set to have a basic/proper understanding of SQL/DBMS through self-study and someone has told that "Hadoop would render SQL obsolete in few years". Can someone please tell me how true is this and what is the relation between SQL and Hadoop (if any). Does Hadoop have a new query language around it? I am really confused. Please help. Or shall I put all misgivings to rest and seriously study SQL in order to have a working knowledge of MySQL server?

PS: I will make sure not to ask a non-technical question like this again. This time help me out.

Comment: Who told you that Hadoop would render SQL obsolete? They serve totally different purposes. One allows you to garner information from (probably) unstructured data (using Mapreduce) while the other requires you to input data according to a schema, but allows for extremely flexible querying and all sorts of ACID guarantees (which is not what Hadoop is about). Hive (and Pig) are languages that have been created to do SQL-like queries against Hadoop. But, frankly, they are totally different beasts, for different scenarious, and the person that told you Hadoop will make SQL obsolete is misguided.

Comment: And, seriously, if you want to learn about RDBMS, consider Postgres over MySQL.

Comment: @JohnBarça Thanks a lot. It helped and it will help me further if you can tell me what Hadoop is in layman terms and how it is totally unrelated to SQL. The guy who told me this initially used to help me in studies (I am studying Computer science subjects on my own), but now for some sick reason is treating me like a "rival-in-making" as I am serious and steady about these subjects. I just love studying these technical stuff seriously, not to be anyone's rival...huh...Please add something more to your comment/answer. Thank you.

Comment: Hmmm, it's been a few years since Hadoop was invented and people still have such "insights".  In any case, this question is primarily opinion-based and hence not appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry, I voted to close it, and then decided it was worth answering.

Answer (score 2):

Hadoop is a distributed system designed for processing massive amounts of, probably, unstructured data -- think webserver logs, text documents, etc. It is generally designed to work on clusters, typically of commodity hardware, where you have a number of processing nodes doing the map/reduce work, and a master that keeps track of/schedules the work of the processing nodes, and deals with failures, job completion and other overview tasks. It uses the concept of [map/reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) to produce some result(s) from the input data. The map part involves asking some question (often something as simple as a count of the occurences of each word in a document, but potentially much more complex) and the reduce part takes the output of the mappers and combines them into a single summary.

Initially using Hadoop required writing your own map/reduce function. For this reason, languages like [Pig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_(programming_tool)) and [Hive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hive) have arisen, which allows for SQL-like statements to be issued against Hadoop clusters, without having to write map/reduce functions.

SQL, on the other hand, has an extremely well-defined syntax for extracting information from structured data.  Provided data is [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and correctly indexed, you can write ad hoc queries using the very well-defined SQL language. RDBMS provide all sorts of other [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) guarantees, to ensure that your data remains consistent and to avoid data loss if a node fails. RDBMS are also designed to run on multiple nodes, but this tends to be more for load balancing and data redundancy (ignoring sharding, which should be combined with redundancy, anyway).

The canonical use case for an RDBMS would be banking transactions, which you certainly don't want to fall over half way through a credit/debit operation, whereas for Hadoop think of counting all the words in all the books ever published in the English (or any other) language -- where you really don't care that much if one node fails and is replaced by another half way through. These are extreme examples, and you can certainly do very much more with both, but I hope serve to indicate the very different business problems that they are designed to address.